# copying data from a SQL server-table to a SQLCE-table

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy some data from a MSSQL table to a SQLCE table in database.net.

I used the following query, connected to the MSSQL db:

```
update [SQLCE-table] ([column])
SET (column) FROM [MSSQL]
```

I keep getting several error messages like `token in error = (]`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not to use some utility for this data copy?

Comment: @vijayp thanx, I would if I could. I'm just familiar with the Import and export Util from SQL expr. and in this util I can't connect to the CE-table. Do you have an alternate suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comment, I would like to suggest that you can use SQL Server Compact bulk copy library

- Check [sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)
- Or you can use [ErikEJ’s blog post to migrate](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) and the utility [SQLCMD](http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/).
- Or create Integration Services packages that write data to SQL Server Compact databases check [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403372.aspx)

Comment: tnx, I'll try one of your suggestions. It looks very prommissing.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive this works for CE
You only have one default or active database
To get to another you need to supply the whole path

```
[instance].[schema_name].[table]
```

Try a 3 part name e.g.

```
[mssql].[dbo].[table]
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a 3rd party tool called full convert enterprise 7 from spectral core (https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert). On the webpage version 6 is shown, but version 7 is also available. 
It's not free, but if you need to transfer data between different servers and database versions and types it could solve your problems. SQLCE is also supported.

I use this tool primary for migrating data from oracle, sybase, firebird and some other to sql.
Even a downgrade (sql 2014 > 2008) is possible and very quick even for larger databases.